# Importing missing State in State and Countries Picklist via API

Tags: country-and-state

I am trying to import a missing state code in Italy, SU (see https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:IT IT-SU) so I created the state code manually on a scratch org and I fetched the modified metadata (Address.settings.xml)

As I try to create a new scratch org pushing that part of metadata, the creation fails:

```
[Failed]: Update of AddressSettings Address: Error: Invalid iso code SU for state Sud Sardegna in country Italy
```

How does one create a missing state via API?

Answer (score 1):

As it seems to me, you can't create new ones via metadata api.
[See documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_addresssettings.htm)

> You can use the Metadata API to edit existing states, countries, and territories in state and country/territory picklists. You can’t use the Metadata API to create or delete new states, countries, or territories.

I have the same issue, as for integration reasons I need an N/A state for every country, and it would be a pain to create it manually in Salesforce setup...